# Need to replace "$$/fullpath/to/unrestricted.zip$$" in .xml file in linux using sed command

Tags: bash, shell, sed

sed command is not replacing due to special characters

```
user$ sed -i '.bak' 's/$$\/fullpath\/to\/unrestricted.zip$$/test/g' testsfg.xml
user$ cat testsfg.xml
<data key='user.sb.JCE_DIST_FILE,com.ibm.sterling.integrator.install.offering' value='$$/fullpath/to/unrestricted.zip$$'/>


user$ sed -i '.bak' 's/$$\/fullpath\/to\/unrestricted.zip$$/test/g' testsfg.xml
user$ cat testsfg.xml
<data key='user.sb.JCE_DIST_FILE,com.ibm.sterling.integrator.install.offering' value='test'/>
```

Comment: `sed` or RegEx engines in general, are not meant to parse syntax of complex markup languages like XML. Use an XML processor/parser instead, like `xsltproc` or `saxon`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You want to change `$$/fullpath/to/unrestricted.zip$$` to `test`, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape special characters with `\`.

Try this command instead:

```
sed -i '.bak' 's/\$\$\/fullpath\/to\/unrestricted\.zip\$\$/test/g' testsfg.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$` in regular expression matches end of line, [reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html). `sed` is smart enough and it things that (only) the last `$` means the end of line.

Notice that if I remove the part after the pre-last `$`, it works:

```
sed 's@$$/fullpath/to/unrestricted.zip$$@test@' <<'EOF'
<data key='user.sb.JCE_DIST_FILE,com.ibm.sterling.integrator.install.offering' value='$$/fullpath/to/unrestricted.zip$
EOF
```

will output:

```
<data key='user.sb.JCE_DIST_FILE,com.ibm.sterling.integrator.install.offering' value='test
```

I removed the last `$'/>` characters. The last `$` matches end of line, so only the `$$/fullpath/to/unrestricted.zip$` will get substituted.

To make it work correctly, you have to escape (at least) the last dollar. Like this:

```
 sed 's@$$/fullpath/to/unrestricted.zip$\$@test@'
```

Note you can use any character as `sed` substitute `s` command separator. For example `@` would be a good choice to save you from `\/` escaping slashes all the time.